# Is this WSDL missing the methods?

Tags: java, wcf, wsdl

```
 <wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="myWCF" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:import namespace="" location="http://ip_address/Test/myWCF.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
<wsdl:service name="myWCF"/>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

It is generated from a WCF.
Is it missing something ? because when i generate its client from Java, I don't get the methods, and they doesn't seem to be i the wsdl.

Can someone please confirm me if this wsdl is missing the methods, or that there is something wrong from the server side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what is contained in the WSDL document that is included.
See the WSDL in the second row:

```
<wsdl:import namespace="" location="http://ip_address/Test/myWCF.svc?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
```

Comment: Thank you that was it, i regenerated the client from this url